# Where are the database tables and fields in Banner that relate to Community Education (courses, registration)?

Tags: banner, ods, ellucian-banner

Can anyone please tell me where the database tables and fields on Community Education are in the Oracle database or in ODS?  I've looked through the tables and searched online and through Banner documentation but have found absolutely nothing.  Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

I think that Community Education courses are just another academic level definition in SGHE or Ellucian Banner, therefore you will check the list of availables level from STVLEVL table.
The catalog of public courses from SCBCRSE table and join with SCRLEVL table.
The specific course by term or academic period from SSBCRSE.
The student registration course from SFRSTCR table.

Perhaps this can help you, to take a look.

Comment: BTW for all student tables the owner is SATURN user or schema on banner database